# How to receive image file from android in django?

Tags: android, python, django

I haven't been able to receive and save a file sent from Android in Django.

The file is being sent using retrofit and the following code:

```
@Multipart
@PUT("/users/{id}")
   void modifyPic(
   @Header("auth_token") String token,
   @Path("id") int userid,
   @Part("request[data][param][title]") String title,
   @Part("request[data][param][Photo]") TypedFile avatar,
   Callback<User> cb
);
```

However I have no idea how to receive and save the file in django.

Could someone help me by giving some pointers how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit had few problems with handling files so i really recommend you to upgrade your library from beta1 to beta2 it works better.

In beta2 you make your api look like this -

```
public interface ApiInterface {
        @Multipart
        @POST ("/api/Accounts/editaccount")
        Call<User> editUser (@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Part("file\"; filename=\"pp.png\" ") RequestBody file , @Part("FirstName") RequestBody fname);
    }
```

The 'file' in the part of 'RequestBody file' is the file entity name that you need to access on your server side.

This is how you call this request -

```
File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
        RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), firstNameField.getText().toString());
        Call<User> call = client.editUser(getToken(), fbody, name, id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

This is a copy of code that **ayon115** wrote in the retrofit library discussion on this link - https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063

I used the same concept and it worked for me smoothly.

I really recommend you to go that link and read the discussion about the library and the difference between beta1 to beta2.

If You are having problem testing the server/client.

You can go to www.requestb.in and deploy a test server so you could test out your http requests from your client so you wouldn't need to run your server each time :)

And to test your client you can use the POSTMAN tool to make requests to your server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like:

```
imageInBase64 = request.POST.get('image')
fh = open("test2.jpg", "wb")
fh.write(imageInBase64.decode('base64'))
fh.close()
```